# how to use user defined string in mysql join

Tags: mysql

I am assigning a value to a variable and using it in join. But it seems to be taking it as a literal. How can I fix it?

```
select
@colname:=a.colname
from
a_details a,
b_details b
where
a.id = b.id
and a.value = b.@colname
```

Comment: Can you try rewriting this query without the use of `@colname`?  I can't seem to do it.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do. Can you show some sample input data and the desired result? Note that you can't use an expression to specify a column name to select or join with, you have to give column names literally.

Comment: @Barmar.. Thats what I'm trying to do.. Specify a column name with the expression

Answer (score 0):

Try your code with this fix:

```
select
@colname:=a.colname
from
a_details a,
b_details b
where
a.id = b.id
and a.value = @colname
```

Comment: In my example this work... but i don't understand beacuse u use `where
a.id = b.id
and a.value = @colname`

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify a column name dynamically like that. You can use `CASE` to select the appropriate column, but you have to list them all explicitly.

```
SELECT CASE a.value
        WHEN 'col1' THEN b.col1
        WHEN 'col2' THEN b.col2
        WHEN 'col3' THEN b.col3
        ...
       END AS col
FROM a_details AS a
JOIN b_details AS b ON a.id = b.id
```

If you don't want to write this out in your code, you could use a stored procedure to execute dynamic SQL.